# Python: Accessing Large Tar Files Over HTTP

Tags: python, http, tar

I would like to access very large tar files (several GBs) over HTTP using python without downloading the entire tar file.  Are there any libraries and/or best practices to do this?

Specifically, I would like to list the contents of a large tar file and download one or two documents within it over HTTP.  The entire tar file is many gigabytes in size but the files I am looking for within them are usually only a few kilobytes.  Therefore, I would like to avoid downloading the entire tar file over HTTP.

I understand that HTTP servers support the `Range` [header option](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) and I assume this can be used to access only portions of a tar file. However, I don't see any libraries that take advantage of this over HTTP.  Any ideas?

Comment: I am afraid, tar does not fit for this kind of use. You have better using zip, 7z or others, which provide much better indexing capabilities.
I was researching a solution for exactly the same scenario and found few promising approaches (not using tar, but zip or other more modern format) based on FUSE, which was supposed to provide the Range access to the file. Theoretically, it could work over AWS S3, but it failed in my case. If you have time to provide that file over your Apache, nginx or other web server you manage, then you may have better results then me.

Comment: It should be possible, using `httpfs` (but unfortunately in my usecase this did not work).  `tar` archives are (if they are not compressed using `gzip` so that they become a `.tar.gz` AKA `.tgz` file) can be accessed randomly, and this should be possible via HTTP supporting the range feature as well.